# Couldn't import Django error when I try to startapp

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I usually work on PC's but started to work on projects on my mac. I run Python 3 and when I started a new project I did the following:

1) In main project folder, installed virtualenv and activated it.

2) Install Django and Gunicorn

3) Did startproject

When I try to python3 manage.py startapp www I get an error that Django could not be imported. Below is what was in the terminal:

```
(venv) AB:directory AB$ pip freeze
Django==1.10
gunicorn==19.6.0

(venv) AB:directory AB$ ls
directory   manage.py

(venv) AB:directory AB$ python3 manage.py startpap www

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    import django
ImportError: No module named 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Comment: using python3 but normal pip ? hmm.... did you try using pip3 and install django with it ?

Comment: `startpap` or `startapp`?

Comment: @Take_Care_ no but when I did pip freeze I see that Django 1.10 is installed in venv

Comment: @DeA startapp misspelled it... same result

Comment: What command did you use to create your virtualenv? Seems likely that it is based on Python 2, not 3.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I did pip install virtualenv and then venv virtualenv

Answer (score 15):

Try using

```
python -m pip install django
```

This is the safest way as far as I know

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, make sure you activated virtualenv, since once you close cmd it is no longer activated:

`env\Scripts\activate` in cmd

Now cmd should have (env) just like this: `(env) c:\users\user\PROJECT\..`

Now you can type: `python manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem when I use Pycharm. I solved it by adding:

```
import sys
  sys.path.append('/Users/et/PycharmProjects/Jieba_Analyzer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages')
```

to manage.py

Comment: sys.path.append('path/to/django')